# Efficent way to print statistics where prints should not duplicate

Tags: python, string, list

I have in my program list of 4-element lists, where data are shown it this way`["Name", "Surname", "Base"("A" or "B"), "Description"]`. Elements are sorted by name. I would like to print them into stdout in this way:

```
Surname: surname
Name: name
Base: A
Description: etcetc
```

And if next item's surname is the same, I would like it to print my list:

```
Name: next_name
Base: A
Description: etcetcetc
```

If name, surname are the same and only base is different, it should be:

```
Base: A
Description: etc
```

If first three elements are the same, it should only append the description to previous print.

I know that this can be done with a lot of if statements, but for me this looks ugly. Is it more efficent way to do this in Python?

Comment: can you show what you have done so far, also `["Name", "Surname", "Base"("A" or "B"), "Description"]` are 4 items, and not 3

Comment: You should show a sample of your data. These lists are sublists of another list or what else? And what tools are you using? Should you use built-ins only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to group adjacent elements by a common feature.  By applying this on every "level" of your objects you can do something like:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def groupby_attributes(l):
    for surname, surname_group in groupby(l, key=itemgetter(0)):
        print("Surname: {}".format(surname))
        for name, name_group in groupby(surname_group, key=itemgetter(1)):
            print("Name: {}".format(name))
            for base, base_group in groupby(name_group, key=itemgetter(2)):
                print("Base: {}".format(base))
                for description in map(itemgetter(3), base_group):
                    print("Description: {}".format(description))

groupby_attributes([
    ["surname1", "name1", "A", "Desc1"],
    ["surname1", "name1", "A", "Desc1"],
    ["surname1", "name1", "B", "Desc1"],
    ["surname1", "name2", "A", "Desc1"],
    ["surname2", "name1", "A", "Desc1"],
    ["surname2", "name1", "B", "Desc1"],
    ])
```

prints

```
Surname: surname1
Name: name1
Base: A
Description: Desc1
Description: Desc1
Base: B
Description: Desc1
Name: name2
Base: A
Description: Desc1
Surname: surname2
Name: name1
Base: A
Description: Desc1
Base: B
Description: Desc1
```

Comment: great, thanks! I have one more question - how to remove blank lines between each group of prints?

Comment: This code shouldn't produce any blank lines unless they're part of the input.